# Ledmac \pagelinesep and Makeindex

Tags: indexing, ledmac

I'm doing multiple indices for a document, using `Ledmac` with the `Memoir` class.
By default, page and line numbers (produced using `\edindex[]{}`) are separated by a dash. I actually would like a colon instead. `Ledmac` documentation specifies that :

> The page & linenumber combination is written as `page\pagelinesep line`, where the default definition is `\newcommand{\pagelinesep}{-}` so that an item on page 3, line 5 will be noted as being at 3-5. You can renew \pagelinesep to get a different separator (but it just so happens that - is the default separator used by the MakeIndex program)

So, I've tried with :

```
\renewcommand*{\pagelinesep}{:}
```

or with :

```
\renewcommand{\thepageline}{%
    \thepage : \lineref{\edindexlab\thelabidx}
```

But, if, in both cases, the entries are correctly written in the .idx file, `Makeindex`rejects them, speaking of :

`-- Illegal Arabic digit: position 3 in 60:741.`

Also, I can't add space, or more than one characters, or I get :

`Illegal space within numerals in second argument`

I think the problem is with Makeindex rules, rather than Ledmac. Has anyone an idea ?

[Edit :] Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\makeindex[names]

\renewcommand*{\pagelinesep}{:}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Here is my numbered text.\edindex[names]{text@Text}
\pend
\endnumbering
\printindex[names]
\end{document}
```

If I suppress `\renewcommand*{\pagelinesep}{:}`, everything works fine after the two `pdflatex` compilations, the `makeindex` one, and the last `pdflatex` compilation. Otherwise, I get the error I mentioned.

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: It's done ! Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to prepare a MakeIndex style containing the two lines

```
page_compositor ":"
delim_r ":"
```

Save this as `mystyle.ist` in the same directory as your main file and call `makeindex` by

```
makeindex -s mystyle names
```

MakeIndex has two groups of string constants: input and output strings. For example the `actual` variable, default `"@"`, tells MakeIndex that when it finds an entry of the form

```
\indexentry{abc@def}{1}
```

it will alphabetize the entry as if it were `abc`, but it will output `def`. When indexing LaTeX internal commands that can start with `@`, it's convenient to say

```
actual "="
```

in a style file, so that one can say in the document

```
\index{@ifundefined=\texttt{\string\@ifundefined}}
```

and MakeIndex will do the right thing.

In your case, **ledmac** uses `\pagelinesep` both for the document and the index production, so it's necessary to change `page_compositor` (default `"-"`) so that it can interpret correctly

```
\indexentry{xyz}{1:2}
```

When MakeIndex detects a page range, it will output it with the page numbers separated by the string specified as value of `delim_r` (default `"--"`). Setting

```
delim_r ":"
```

we achieve our goal. Here we are setting an output related string.

There's a number of `.ist` files in `<TeX>/makeindex` (where `<TeX>` represents the main distribution tree on your machine) that can be studied.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. Would you have some reference that you would recommend about writing .ist files ?

Comment: The primary reference is the "LaTeX Companion", but also `texdoc makeindex.man1` is quite informative.